# Thymeleaf Return view with anchor tag

Tags: java, url, path, controller, thymeleaf

I'm facing with the following behaviour using Thymeleaf. I need to return a view with the anchor tag, i.e.

```
@PostMapping("something")
    public String step1Post(@ModelAttribute("ModelResposne")  RInputModel modelResponse, Model model) throws ValidationException, BindException  {
 
        //stuff
        return "view#myform";
    }
```

but it returns an "Error resolving template" issue.
Anybody can help me please? If I'm on the right way of thought?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add myform.html file also.
and full error message. 
Question is still need some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a view name with an anchor (the browser already knows the url it's going to at that point in the process).  You can however return a redirect instead with an anchor in it.

```
return "redirect:/view#myform";
```

You might have to rework your urls a bit. (Can't really be sure with your example code.)